# Create dynamic view in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-json

In my application I am receiving JSON multiple forms like this:

```
"forms":[ {"name": "form1","title": "First Form","order": 1,
           "fields":[
                    "name": "firstName","type": "InputText", "maxLength": "10",
                    "restriction": "text"},
          {"name": "lastName","type": "InputText","maxLength": "10","restriction": "text"}
                    ]
          },
          {"name": "form2","title": "Second Form","order": 2,
          "fields": [
                    {"name": "email","type": "InputText","maxLength": "50","restriction": "email"},
                    {"name": "gender","type": "dropdown","values": [male,female]},
                    {"name": "married","type": "boolean"}
                    ]
          }
       ]
```

**inputText=editText , dropDown=spinner, boolean= checkBox**

I am trying to make my view to be divided into sections for each form ,as you see each form has different fields, can anyone give me the idea to do that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tabbed activity ,  [android Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) , [android swipe view](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) then assign each fields to different sections